# Can something be done to improve the ability to view/review code?

Tags: feature-request

The way code is displayed is better than nothing, I suppose, but long lines scroll out of the code window, and the horizontal scroll bar scrolls off the bottom of the page, so that one must constantly scroll back and forth to read long lines.  This makes it so difficult to examine code that often I just open the browser page source to look at the code (but that's obviously pretty crude too).

Is there anything that can be done about this (or am I the only one that it bugs)?  At the very least an option to display lines folded would be appreciated, or perhaps a way to expand the width of the code window.

Comment: Tell the OP to stop making his lines to ridiculously long. He'll be doing you and his colleagues a favour. ;)

Comment: We need an option to wrap the code lines if it is out of the screen. User can then align the lines to make it look better.